# What is the difference beteween Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal and Get-AzureADServicePrincipal?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, powershell-2.0

I have written powershell script to read the Service Principal for based on the appId as below:

```
$DirectoryApp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal | where AppId -eq $DirectoryAppId
```

But I cannot find the service principal to read permission to create azure ad application.Interestingly if I use the service principal object Id is can retrieve the service principal. What is effecting in this case not to read the service principal based on the

```
$DirectoryAppId = 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000
```

I also see two different approaches, `Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal` and `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal`.

What is the difference beteween `Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal` and `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal` ?

Answer (score 4):

First, how to get one sp via Applicaiton Id:

**Azure RM Powershell:**

```
$sp =  Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal | Where-Object{$_.ApplicationId -eq "00000000-c781-4224-9b91-ad15a8179ba0"}
```

**Azure AD Powershell:**

```
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal | Where-Object{$_.AppId -eq "00000000-c4e2-40cb-96a7-ac90df92685c"}
```

> What is the difference beteween Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal and
>   Get-AzureADServicePrincipal ?

These two commands are from different Powershell modules.

`Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal` is from [Azure RM Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.3.0).

`Get-AzureADServicePrincipal` is from [Azure AD Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/overview?view=azureadps-2.0).

If you want to use AAD only, Azure AD Powershell is better. If you want to use Azure Subscription and apart feature of AAD via Poweshell, Azure RM powershell is better.

Comment: Hi @jithu reddy , is this answer helpful?